# unable to unregister dbus signal for ble notifications

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus

I am using python dbus library to register for receiving ble packets from a device. However, after a disconnect and reconnect, I am getting multiple callbacks. I tried unregistering the singal but it seems to have no effect - following is what I am currently doing -

```
class Gatt(object):
dbus_if = 'org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1'

    def __init__(self, bus, char_path):
        self.char_path = char_path
        self.bus = bus
        prop_man = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERV_NAME, self.char_path),
                                  'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        props = prop_man.GetAll(self.dbus_if)
        self.uuid = props[dbus.String('UUID')]
        self.notifying = props[dbus.String('Notifying')]
        nom = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERV_NAME, char_path), 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
        self.signal_on_property_changed = nom.connect_to_signal('PropertiesChanged', self.on_char_property_changed)
        print('New Gatt Device {}'.format(str(self.uuid)))
        self.dbus_if_handle = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERV_NAME, self.char_path),
                       self.dbus_if)

def clear_signal(self):
    self.bus.remove_signal_receiver(self.on_char_property_changed, self.signal_on_property_changed)
```

At this point I am suspecting that the remove_signal_receiver() has wrong arguments and thus silently failing without giving me proper results.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove signal match created by `self.signal_on_property_changed = nom.connect_to_signal(...)` you need to save the signal created by this function and then call the method `remove()` on this signal.

Example:

```
# Create signal
self.signal_on_property_changed = nom.connect_to_signal(...)
....
# Remove signal
self.signal_on_property_changed.remove()
```

Comment: Forgot to mark as answer. This is the most easy way to remove signal :-). Thanks